# SQL SERVER/ASP syntax error near INNER

Tags: asp-classic, sql-server-2008-r2

I have two databases on separate SQL servers. They have been linked in SQL Server. I can't move the databases to the same server.

I am trying to use an inner join to display a small set of specific information. Basically I need to display one column from database A(NurQueryResults) if the VisitID = the Account Number from database B. I have succesfully connected to both databases (using a connection string) indivdually in the asp page with separate connection strings. I have verified the column names in each database. I'm getting a syntax error in my SQL code. Here is the code I'm trying to use:

```
    SELECT Response, VisitID, QueryID, RowUpdateTime FROM [dbo].NurQueryResults WHERE QueryID = FALL.RISK1

INNER JOIN [dbo].View_CareProviderWithPatientAtLocation
ON [dbo].NurQueryResult.VisitID = [dbo].View_CareProviderWithPatientAtLocation.AccountNumber    

ORDER BY RowUpdateDateTime DESC
```

I'm using Dreamweaver. The page is .asp and I'm have been using the Insert Recordset command. That is the area I am trying to enter the above code in to. I get the syntax error when I try the "test" button in the recordset window.

I have tried listing out the server/database name/table name for database B and still received the syntax error. Is it something incorrect in the SQL code? Or do you think it has to do with my connection to the linked server? Or should I be taking a completey different approach to get that data?

Comment: move your where statement after the join on.   basically sql is formatted as select what from which jointed to what where conditions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT Response, VisitID, QueryID, RowUpdateTime 
FROM [dbo].NurQueryResults     
INNER JOIN [dbo].View_CareProviderWithPatientAtLocation
ON [dbo].NurQueryResult.VisitID = [dbo].View_CareProviderWithPatientAtLocation.AccountNumber    
WHERE QueryID = FALL.RISK1
ORDER BY RowUpdateDateTime DESC
```

Comment: That got rid of the syntax error, but now I'm getting an Invalid object name error for dbo.ViewCareProviderWithPatientAtLocation.

Comment: The table view does exist. I can connect to and query it on it's own without issue. I tried listing out the server/database/table name after the inner join and got the message that the server couldn't be found in sys.server. If necessary, execute the stored procedure sp_addlinkedservers to add the server to sys.servers. I sent this on to our network admins. I don't have access to SQL server myself... Thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Response, VisitID, QueryID, RowUpdateTime 
FROM [dbo].NurQueryResults 

INNER JOIN [dbo].View_CareProviderWithPatientAtLocation
ON [dbo].NurQueryResult.VisitID = [dbo].View_CareProviderWithPatientAtLocation.AccountNumber    

WHERE QueryID = FALL.RISK1
ORDER BY RowUpdateDateTime DESC
```